# iOS Is it possible to change orientation of device when default device rotation is off?

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation

Today I was surprised by a feature of camera in apple when I rotate device to landscape mode icons were also rotated in landscape mode, Although the Automatic rotation was off for my device, How it can happen?

**If default device rotation is off then how can camera app know that device orientation is changed?**

I double checked my phones settings of Auto-Rotation and they were off.

Answer (score 1):

The device-orientation setting is ignored for the camera. This was done so that people can keep orientation-lock on **and** take landscape photos at the same time, without having to constantly change the setting.

Comment: Is this statement documented by Apple?